# How does the dispatcher work when mixing sync/async with serial/concurrent queue?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, queue, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

In Grand Central Dispatch, how does the dispatcher work with different queues (`serial` and `concurrent`) when using the `dispatch_sync` function and the `dispatch_async` function?

Comment: I made this question and answered by myself to show as "article" how the dispatcher works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we need two type of **queue**: one **serial** and one **concurrent**:

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue =
dispatch_queue_create("com.matteogobbi.dispex.serial_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue =
dispatch_queue_create("com.matteogobbi.dispex.concurrent_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

So, we can start with the first experiment, using a **serial queue** and all `dispatch_async` function to add our block to the queue:

```
/* Dispatch async with serial queue */
NSLog(@"\n\nDISPATCH: Async - QUEUE: Serial");

NSLog(@"block 1 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 1");
});

NSLog(@"block 2 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 2");
});

NSLog(@"block 3 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 3");
});

NSLog(@"block 4 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 4");
});

NSLog(@"block 5 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 5");
});

NSLog(@"block 6 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 6");
});

NSLog(@"block 7 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 7");
});

NSLog(@"block 8 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 8");
});

NSLog(@"block 9 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 9");
});

NSLog(@"block 10 added");
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 10");
});

NSLog(@"ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE --> FUNCTION RETURNED");
```

> DISPATCH: Async - QUEUE: Serial
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.468 dispex[4346:60b] block 1 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.468 dispex[4346:60b] block 2 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.468 dispex[4346:1303] block 1
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.469 dispex[4346:1303] block 2
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.468 dispex[4346:60b] block 3 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.469 dispex[4346:1303] block 3
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.469 dispex[4346:60b] block 4 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.469 dispex[4346:1303] block 4
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.469 dispex[4346:60b] block 5 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.470 dispex[4346:60b] block 6 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.470 dispex[4346:1303] block 5
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:60b] block 7 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:1303] block 6
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:1303] block 7
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:60b] block 8 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:1303] block 8
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.471 dispex[4346:60b] block 9 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.472 dispex[4346:60b] block 10 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.472 dispex[4346:1303] block 9
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.472 dispex[4346:1303] block 10
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.472 dispex[4346:60b] ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE
>   --> FUNCTION RETURNED

As you can see, the block are added to the queue but **in the meantime the dispatcher begin to execute them**. This is a characteristic of the `dispatcher_async` function, that is **add block to the queue without wait that them finish to be executed**. In other words, if you are using `dispatch_async` in a function, the function return immediately and in the meantime the block is executing. This is extremely useful! In this example i used NSLog to report when the block are added to the queue and so this does to be the execution slower and causes the log

> ALL BLOCK ADDED

at the end. But as we will see after, without logs it will be wrote at the beginning. Due the fact that we are using a serial queue, the block are executed in the order of adding.

Next:

```
/* Just wait before begin with the next test */
dispatch_group_wait(group_async_serial, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


/* Dispatch sync with serial queue */
NSLog(@"\n\nDISPATCH: Sync - QUEUE: Serial");

NSLog(@"block 1 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 1");
});

NSLog(@"block 2 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 2");
});

NSLog(@"block 3 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 3");
});

NSLog(@"block 4 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 4");
});

NSLog(@"block 5 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 5");
});

NSLog(@"block 6 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 6");
});

NSLog(@"block 7 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 7");
});

NSLog(@"block 8 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 8");
});

NSLog(@"block 9 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 9");
});

NSLog(@"block 10 added");
dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 10");
});

NSLog(@"ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE --> FUNCTION RETURNED");
```

> DISPATCH: Sync - QUEUE: Serial
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.473 dispex[4346:60b] block 1 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.474 dispex[4346:60b] block 1
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.474 dispex[4346:60b] block 2 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.474 dispex[4346:60b] block 2
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.475 dispex[4346:60b] block 3 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.475 dispex[4346:60b] block 3
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.475 dispex[4346:60b] block 4 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.475 dispex[4346:60b] block 4
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.476 dispex[4346:60b] block 5 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.476 dispex[4346:60b] block 5
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.476 dispex[4346:60b] block 6 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.477 dispex[4346:60b] block 6
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.477 dispex[4346:60b] block 7 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.477 dispex[4346:60b] block 7
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.477 dispex[4346:60b] block 8 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.478 dispex[4346:60b] block 8
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.478 dispex[4346:60b] block 9 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.478 dispex[4346:60b] block 9
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.479 dispex[4346:60b] block 10 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.479 dispex[4346:60b] block 10
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.479 dispex[4346:60b] ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE
>   --> FUNCTION RETURNED

In this example we are using `dispatch_sync` function with a **serial queue**. It's very easy to see that all block are added when the previous block finish to be executed. This is a characteristic of `dispatch_sync`. In other words the function doesn't return until the block finish to be executed. Due the fact that is a serial queue, the order also here is respected.

Next:

```
/* Dispatch async with concurrent queue */
NSLog(@"\n\nDISPATCH: Async - QUEUE: Concurrent");
dispatch_group_t group_async_concurrent = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 1");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 2");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 3");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 4");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 5");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 6");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 7");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 8");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 9");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 10");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 11");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 12");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 13");
});

dispatch_group_async(group_async_concurrent, concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 14");
});

NSLog(@"ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE --> FUNCTION RETURNED");
```

> DISPATCH: Async - QUEUE: Concurrent
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:60b] ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE
>   --> FUNCTION RETURNED
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:1303] block 1
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3503] block 2
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3603] block 3
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3803] block 5
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3703] block 4
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3903] block 6
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3a03] block 7
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.480 dispex[4346:3b03] block 8
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.482 dispex[4346:1303] block 9
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.483 dispex[4346:3503] block 10
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.483 dispex[4346:3803] block 12
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.483 dispex[4346:3703] block 13
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.483 dispex[4346:3903] block 14
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.483 dispex[4346:3603] block 11

As i said before, here i show how work `dispatch_async` but with a **concurrent queue**.
It's really interesting because without NSLog to show when the block is added, you can see how ALL BLOCKS are added before that the first block is executed. This behaviour **is not constant**. **Can happen that block1 is executed and immediately after the `dispatch_async` finish to add all blocks to the queue and then continue to execute other blocks**. Another thing to note, is that the block are executed concurrently, and so them doesn't respect the order of adding and also this behaviour is not constant but depend from the CPU usage, performance and many other things.

Next:

```
/* Just wait before begin with the next test */
dispatch_group_wait(group_async_concurrent, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


/* Dispatch sync with concurrent queue */
NSLog(@"\n\nDISPATCH: Sync - QUEUE: Concurrent");

NSLog(@"block 1 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 1");
});

NSLog(@"block 2 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 2");
});

NSLog(@"block 3 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 3");
});

NSLog(@"block 4 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 4");
});

NSLog(@"block 5 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 5");
});

NSLog(@"block 6 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 6");
});

NSLog(@"block 7 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 7");
});

NSLog(@"block 8 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 8");
});

NSLog(@"block 9 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 9");
});

NSLog(@"block 10 added");
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"block 10");
});

NSLog(@"ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE --> FUNCTION RETURNED");
```

> DISPATCH: Sync - QUEUE: Concurrent
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.486 dispex[4346:60b] block 1 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.486 dispex[4346:60b] block 1
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.487 dispex[4346:60b] block 2 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.487 dispex[4346:60b] block 2
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.487 dispex[4346:60b] block 3 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.488 dispex[4346:60b] block 3
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.488 dispex[4346:60b] block 4 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.488 dispex[4346:60b] block 4
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.489 dispex[4346:60b] block 5 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.489 dispex[4346:60b] block 5
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.489 dispex[4346:60b] block 6 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.489 dispex[4346:60b] block 6
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.490 dispex[4346:60b] block 7 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.490 dispex[4346:60b] block 7
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.490 dispex[4346:60b] block 8 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.491 dispex[4346:60b] block 8
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.491 dispex[4346:60b] block 9 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.491 dispex[4346:60b] block 9
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.492 dispex[4346:60b] block 10 added
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.492 dispex[4346:60b] block 10
>
> 2014-04-08 14:43:16.492 dispex[4346:60b] ALL BLOCK ADDED TO THE QUEUE
>   --> FUNCTION RETURNED

Finally, here we used `dispatch_sync` with **concurrent queue**. It seems perfectly equal to the couple sync/serial. In this case is so. This behaviour is due the fact that also if the queue is concurrent, it haven't got other block to execute because we are using the synchronous dispatcher and so, it wait to add the next block until the actual doesn't finish to be executed. This type of couple (**sync/concurrent**) is useful if we are also adding to the queue, blocks with `dispatch_async`. In that case the dispatcher could have other blocks added to the queue to be executed.

Hope that this mini demonstration has been useful ;)

Cheers!