# can anyone explain this behaviour of "dispatch_async" in this example..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, message-queue

What i was trying to do was to implement Key-Value Observing pattern.

I have MasterViewController, DetailViewController, and random class called Animal which has only one property called "name".( by the way, this project was built from **Master-View controller template**)

```
// Animal.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Animal : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@end
```

In detailViewController has just one label displaying the name property from animal class using segue. And, also i have Observer added to animal Obj.

```
//detailViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@end


//implementation 
@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        [newDetailItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];

    }
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
       self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem name];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

In MasterViewController which is a tableViewController, whenever pressing "+" bar button, it will set cell's detail to the name from Animal class. And, at this time in this method( insertNewObject:) i'm simulating downloading something by just putting it to sleep(5);
And Then, it will assign random number to the name property from animal.
When you change the name property, since i've already add Observer to Animal, it's gonna notify me and "Update" my Label!.
**SO, Sinarrio would be that once you press "+" button, you click the cell that just got inserted and wait for the original label to change.**

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc]init];
    animal.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animal number %d", _objects.count+1 ];
    [_objects insertObject: animal atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        sleep(5);// simulating downloading.

        NSLog(@"3");
        NSLog(@"4");
        // assign random number.
        animal.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animal number %d", rand()];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"7");
            [self.tableView reloadData]; // **it got called after excuting NSLog(@"8") why..?**
            NSLog(@"8");
        });
        NSLog(@"5");
        NSLog(@"6");
    });

    NSLog(@"2");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"1");
    Animal *animal = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [animal name];

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Animal *animal = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:animal];
    }
}
```

So, Here's what i've got wired behaviour.
As for oder of dispatch thread, i printed the number but some time it has different order.
But, i can't really understand when i got this order :
1 2 3 4 7 5 6 8 1 
I thought inside single thread execution, it shouldn't be jumped around especially 7 8 1 order part..

And, other question is that after 3 and 4 , since it change name property, my configure method gets called right away BUT **it didn't update or refresh anything until.. actually after for a while 5 6 7 8 printed**

Lastly,
After you press "+" button and you go back and forth from detail to master view Then
 you Got this error and **why..**?
[image]

PS: when KVO calls My configure method after name property changed, when i debug, the name property has been changed but it didn't update..

Comment: Turn on zombies in your scheme and see if you get a more useful error message.  I suspect that "animal" has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for your first question **you need to understand how the dispatcher work**.

Using the `dispatch_async` function in the **global_queue** (that is **concurrent**) **the order** of the execution's thread **can change each time**. Is not constant. To understand better, read my article written here on stackoverflow:

[How does the dispatcher work when mixing sync/async with serial/concurrent queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940154/how-does-the-dispatcher-work-when-mixing-sync-async-with-serial-concurrent-queue)

Another thing is that your are declaring the `@property NSString *name` as `atomic`. In fact when you don't write anything, `atomic` is the default value. I don't know if you made this voluntarily, but in any case, i would write:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

Try so to run your code again and also read my article. Now i will read better your post and i could write something else in this response.

Comment: First of all, i can't tell you how much i appreciate you reading my post sir. I did change to nonatomic and run again trying back and forth but then agian i got the same error message. By the way, why would i choose nonatomic for the situation where more than one thread are involved..? i thought i would make it synchronised..

Comment: Yes is right, but you should use copy ;) Give me some minutes to read your code.

Comment: Without your code in my hands is not easy find the problem. The first important thing is that you understood how dispatch_async and sync work. Then, can you see when crash, what is the value of name? seems deallocated..

Comment: @MatteoGobbi care to explain why he needs `(copy,nonatomic)` ? `copy` is needed only when the object is mutable. There's no need of using neither `copy` nor `nonatomic` here. Since more than one thread are modifying `name` object , `atomic` is more safe.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx for `atomic`/`nonatomic` it's ok, if he need can use `atomic`. But for `strong` no. In fact an `NSString` should be declared `copy`, because can accept instance of `NSMutableString`. Here i don't have many space, but you can read a good explanation with code example here: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/use-copy-for-nsstring-properties/

Comment: @MatteoGobbi just because `NSString` can accept `NSMutableString`, it's not a good practice to always use `copy`. Because it's less efficient.It's less efficient because an actual memory allocation and copy must occur. If you use a `strong` property and assign an `NSMutableString`, that `NSMutableString` will be retained, but can still be modified. If you use `copy`, an immutable copy will be created when you assign an `NSMutableString`, from then on "copy" on the property will just retain, because the copy of the mutable string is itself immutable.

Comment: you are not right..instead is a best practices and you should have a look on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like animal.name is immutable. Multiple assignment hurts.